Call a function at VimEnter event only if vim was launched with a readable file as argument
Consider the following auto-group:
augroup FOO
    autocmd!
    autocmd VimEnter * Foo()
augroup END

I want that Foo() is invoked only if Vim is launched with a filename argument. For example,

vim --clean shall call Foo()
vim shall call Foo()
vim bar.txt shall not call Foo()
vim --clean bar.txt shall not call Foo()

How to modify the auto-group?
EDIT: At the moment, I wrote a function, but there must be an easier way, no?
def OpenFoo()
    # Iterate through the command-line arguments
    for arg in v:argv[1 : ]
        # Check if the argument is not an option (doesn't start with '-')
        if arg[0] !=# '-'
            # Check if the argument is a valid file. If so, don't call Foo()
            # files.
            if filereadable(arg)
                return
            endif
        endif
    endfor

    Foo()
enddef

augroup FOO
    autocmd!
    autocmd VimEnter * OpenFoo()
augroup END


I think this is the correct way. In your function, check the number of arguments given and don't do anything if no argument was given. Note: You cannot react to --clean. The whole idea of --clean is to not load any custom configuration files.

Thanks! You mean to surround the for loop with if len(v:argv) > 1 ... ?

First, as mentioned by Christian Brabandt in a comment: The --clean option is used to not load any custom configuration files. You are right that v:argv will contain these flags as well, but I think you should ignore such arguments in your function as it seems to be irrelevant to your original question.
Now, to have a function Foo() to be only executed if there is no readable file argument, it seems you are on the right track. I would do something like this with regular Vimscript:
function! OpenFoo() abort
  let l:readable_args = filter(copy(v:argv), { _, x ->
        \ !empty(x) && filereadable(x)
        \})
  if len(l:readable_args) == 0 | return | endif

  call Foo()
endfunction

augroup FOO
  autocmd!
  autocmd VimEnter * OpenFoo()
augroup END

Here vi first copy() the argument list, because filter() will mutate the argument and v:argv is immutable. Next, we filter it such that only readable filename arguments are kept. If the list is empty, then there is no readable filename argument.

I converted in vim9 and it works super! Thanks!

Is it too early in the startup sequence to use argv() instead of v:argv?

Glad to hear it was useful, Barzi! @D.BenKnoble to be honest, I don't know the answer.

@D.BenKnoble why use argv() instead of v:argv? Are there any benefits?

@Barzi2001 I _believe _ (haven’t confirmed) that with argv() you would not have to filter options, for example, since I think it produces only the file arguments
